# jsf and /j_spring_security_check how to show auth error message(as growl or p:message)?

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security

I use basic login operation with /j_spring_security_check.(jsf2.2,spring-sec4,primefaces5)But when I enter the wrong password or username,nothing happens on browser.How to control error message ? if I use CustomLoginBean , maybe I can do that.But I want to use that 
 `action='#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check'`

 How can I do that without customLoginBean ? or is it possible? I want to show error message on browser like `"This password/username is incorrect!"`
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never used form based authentication in the last years, but programmatic. Just my €0.02

Comment: hm i'm sorry for my bad description.I use /j_spring_security_check in form action tag and working properly.But how do I make a print screen of an incorrect login.İf you enter the incorrect login info,this login page is not saying "incorrect username or password try again..".I want to give warning on this page as above.I dont have managed bean for login page.how can I do that without managedbean?thanks in advance @BalusC